# Attempting to establish hrmp channels on rococo-local reports `Execution errored at 0: Unimplemented`

Tags: xcm, rococo-local, hrmp

I have a local-rococo setup between parachain `3015` (sender) and parachain `2000` (recipient). I was able to send `hrmpInitOpenChannel` successfully to the recipient, followed by `hrmpAcceptOpenChannel`

The recipient parachain happily accepts the `hrmpAcceptOpenChannel` request, but sender parachain fails right after the `HrmpChannelAccepted` event with `Unimplemented error`.

The log trace snippet below is telling part of the story, I appreciate it if there are any pointers here on where would be the next place to look.

```
2022-07-01 19:40:00.027 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, message: Xcm([HrmpChannelAccepted { recipient: 2000 }]), weight_limit: 500000000000, weight_credit: 0    
2022-07-01 19:40:00.027 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: FixedWeightBounds message: Xcm([HrmpChannelAccepted { recipient: 2000 }])    
2022-07-01 19:40:00.027 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::barriers: TakeWeightCredit origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, message: Xcm([HrmpChannelAccepted { recipient: 2000 }]), max_weight: 1000000000, weight_credit: 0    
2022-07-01 19:40:00.027 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::barriers: AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, message: Xcm([HrmpChannelAccepted { recipient: 2000 }]), max_weight: 1000000000, weight_credit: 0    
2022-07-01 19:40:00.027 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::barriers: AllowUnpaidExecutionFrom origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, message: Xcm([HrmpChannelAccepted { recipient: 2000 }]), max_weight: 1000000000, weight_credit: 0    

2022-07-01 19:40:00.027 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute: origin: Some(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), total_surplus/refunded: 0/0, error_handler_weight: 0    
2022-07-01 19:40:00.027 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: result: Err(ExecutorError { index: 0, xcm_error: Unimplemented, weight: 0 })    
2022-07-01 19:40:00.027 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: Execution errored at 0: Unimplemented (original_origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here })
```

For more context: the first step is to submit `polkadotXcm.send` Rococo encoded `hrmpInitOpenChannel` extrinsic via the sender (3015) which in turn submits an upward message to Rococo

[image: hrmpInitOpenChannel request snippet]

Checking `hrmpOpenChannelRequestCount`, appears to have executed as expected, there is 1 open request for 3015.

[image: open channels count]

In the second step to accept the request, the encoded `hrmpAcceptOpenChannel` extrinsic is submitted via the recipient (2000) -- and it appears to have executed successfully on Rococo as seen from the snippet below:

[image]

Here is the [script](https://gist.github.com/mohamedelshami/37a97a75f1b778de2d129b2a5b61e2f0) I use to perform the above operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the logs and your comment, it looks like you are sending `hrmpInitOpenChannel` and `hrmpAcceptOpenChannel` to the other parachain? You actually want to send these to the *Relay Chain*. If that doesn't work, please post the exact calls you made and I'll take another look.

---

EDIT based up question update:

I see why you are confused, because of the `HrmpChannelAccepted` message sent to the parachain. Indeed, that error [comes from here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/ac3cc36/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L506) but just means that the parachain does nothing on receiving that instruction.

However, as long as it was successful on the Relay Chain (which it looks like it was), then the channel is established and you can use it. To verify, look at `hrmp.hrmpChannels` and make sure that the channel is there.

The script you used also looks to handle things correctly.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I'm showing the xcm trace from the sender parachain. As I understand,  `hrmpInitOpenChannel` and `hrmpAcceptOpenChannel` requests are encoded on the relay chain and then instantiated on each respective parachain via sudo polkadotXcm.send. Let me provide more context in the post.

Comment: OK I see, updated response.

Comment: That was it, the output below. Beside the "Unimplemented" error, what actually confused me is `hrmp.AcceptedChannelRequestCount(2000)` returns 0. 

hrmp.hrmpChannels: Option<PolkadotRuntimeParachainsHrmpHrmpChannel>

{
  maxCapacity: 8
  maxTotalSize: 8,192
  maxMessageSize: 1,048,576
  msgCount: 0
  totalSize: 0
  mqcHead: null
  senderDeposit: 0
  recipientDeposit: 0
}